# Logstash v2.2.0 fails to start as a service

Tags: service, logstash, init.d

```
+ PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
+ export PATH
+ id -u
+ [ 0 -ne 0 ]
+ name=logstash
+ pidfile=/var/run/logstash.pid
+ LS_USER=logstash
+ LS_GROUP=logstash
+ LS_HOME=/var/lib/logstash
+ LS_HEAP_SIZE=1g
+ LS_LOG_DIR=/var/log/logstash
+ LS_LOG_FILE=/var/log/logstash/logstash.log
+ LS_CONF_DIR=/etc/logstash/conf.d
+ LS_OPEN_FILES=16384
+ LS_NICE=19
+ LS_OPTS=
+ [ -r /etc/default/logstash ]
+ . /etc/default/logstash
+ KILL_ON_STOP_TIMEOUT=0
+ [ -r /etc/sysconfig/logstash ]
+ program=/opt/logstash/bin/logstash
+ args=agent -f /etc/logstash/conf.d -l /var/log/logstash/logstash.log 
+ status
+ [ -f /var/run/logstash.pid ]
+ cat /var/run/logstash.pid
+ pid=12716
+ kill -0 12716
+ return 2
+ code=2
+ [ 2 -eq 0 ]
+ start
+ LS_JAVA_OPTS= -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/logstash
+ HOME=/var/lib/logstash
+ export PATH HOME LS_HEAP_SIZE LS_JAVA_OPTS LS_USE_GC_LOGGING
+ id -Gn logstash
+ + sed s/,$//
tr   ,
+ echo 
+ SGROUPS=logstash
+ [ ! -z logstash ]
+ EXTRA_GROUPS=--groups logstash
+ ulimit -n 16384
+ echo 22073
+ echo logstash started.
logstash started.
+ return 0
+ code=0
+ exit 0
+ nice -n 19 chroot --userspec logstash:logstash --groups logstash / sh -c 
    cd /var/lib/logstash
    ulimit -n 16384
    exec "/opt/logstash/bin/logstash" agent -f /etc/logstash/conf.d -l /var/log/logstash/logstash.log
```

---

The above is the command output when the logstash service is started.
(Got this by adding -x switch to the start of the init.d script - **#!/bin/sh -x**)

> **Logstash v2.2.0 is installed using the DEB package on Ubuntu 14.04**

When I run the exec command that is used by the init script (as seen in the above output) logstash startups pretty fine and works flawlessly

```
"/opt/logstash/bin/logstash" agent -f /etc/logstash/conf.d -l /var/log/logstash/logstash.log
```

There is something in the init.d service script that causes logstash to fail as a service. I suspect the **nice** command that the init script uses.

**Do you guys see any issues with the '*nice*' command that is being used in the init script ?**

```
    + nice -n 19 chroot --userspec logstash:logstash --groups logstash / sh -c 
    cd /var/lib/logstash
    ulimit -n 16384
    exec "/opt/logstash/bin/logstash" agent -f /etc/logstash/conf.d -l /var/log/logstash/logstash.log
```

Comment: Is this new installation on this server or have you installed then removed logstash on this machine earlier?

Comment: I have uninstalled previous logstash installation (I believe that was v1.4).

Answer (score 1):

When you have uninstalled older version, the `logstash` user and group was also removed. Now with new installation a new `logstash` user and group was created with different `uid` and `gid`. Yet the ownership of common logstash directories belongs to the old `logstash` `uid` and `gid`.
Now when you start new logstash it tries to read/write to this dir and fails hence logstash not running.
Try changing ownership of these dir and start `logstash`

```
chown -R logstash:logstash /var/log/logstash
chown -R logstash:logstash /var/lib/logstash
chown -R logstash:logstash /etc/logstash
rm -rf /var/run/logstash.pid
/etc/init.d/logstash start
```

Comment: It was an early celebration. Changing the permissions did not fix it. The service status said "running" for a longer time than usual which led me to believe that it was fixed. When I checked again it stopped :(

Comment: There is another issue. Even if I run it in the foreground with a file input in the logstash conf file, it starts up but throws another error - Looks like it is a known issue since v1.5. Check this comment of mine on the issue on github - https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/3127#issuecomment-182370462